# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in Select query C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I have a table in a MS Access database (`.mdb`) that has a bunch of columns. I ran the following SQL query and it returned everything in the table to my C# application (Visual Studio 2012 Express).

```
Select OperatorNo, DateTime, FuelIssued, PreviousCredit, Term 
From TransAll 
Where Term = 'Invalid'
```

Now I am trying to add more criteria to the `where` clause. I am trying to do a date range on the table name DateTime to be between a specific range.

Here is the SQL select statement I created via code:

```
Select OperatorNo, DateTime, FuelIssued, PreviousCredit, Term 
From TransAll  
Where Term = 'Invalid' 
  And DateTime Between '2018/6/24 00:00:00' and '2018/6/30 23:59:59'
```

I imported the access database into SQL Server express so I could manually figure out the SQL select command then fixed the code. The code is working in the SQL Server database. But in the C# code I am now I am getting an error:

> Unhandled exception of type system.data.oledb.oledbexception occurred in system.data.dll.  Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Here is my code in question:

```
string tmpString = strSelectQuery + strWhereClause;
private DataSet myDS = new DataSet();
oledbDataAdapter MyAdapter = new oledbDataAdapter(tmpString, MyConnection);
MyAdapter.Fill(myDS); //this is where the error happens when I run my code
dgvResults.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dgvResults.AutoSize = true;
dgvResults.DataSource = myDS;
dgvResults.DataMember = "Table";
dgvResults.ReadOnly = true;

if (dgvResults.RowCount == 0)
     MessageBox.Show("No Data for that Date Range/Week");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Placing ticks around the pseudo DateTime data indicates text which is not DateTime.  Always use SQL Parameters.  Always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your SQL work, use Access SQL syntax for the string expressions for the date values:

```
Select 
    OperatorNo, DateTime, FuelIssued, PreviousCredit, Term 
From 
    TransAll  
Where 
    Term = 'Invalid' 
    And 
    DateTime Between #2018/6/24 00:00:00# And #2018/6/30 23:59:59#
```

But, as already noted, use parameters. Much easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated by @Plutonix, using parameters instead of string concat to create your statement will greatly help. It will also avoid sql injection attacks.

```
string query = "Select OperatorNo, DateTime, FuelIssued, PreviousCredit, Term from TransAll where Term = @Term And DateTime Between @Startdate and @Enddate";

var cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandText = query;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Term", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = termString;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Startdate", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = startDate; // of type date
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Enddate", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = endDate; // of type date
```

This way you can tell where error can also occur. Please try to dispose of sqlconnection etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion here.  I have actually finished this project and it worked wonderfully.  I have also used it in my new project as well.